# failed to execute: No attribute named 'username' is defined - Gatling Java CSV

Tags: java, gatling, scala-gatling

I'm trying to read a csv file using Gatling and Java but I get this error failed to execute: No attribute named 'username' is defined and am a bit confused as I'm trying to debug it and I can print out the values from the file using the transform method, but I'm not sure why it's not being found by my simulation.

```
Slf4j
public class LoginSimulation extends Simulation {

    HttpProtocolBuilder httpProtocol = http
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL) // Here is the root for all relative URLs
            .shareConnections();


    ScenarioBuilder scn1 = scenario("states").exec(
            http("Authorize - /authorize")
                    .post("http://my.api.io/authorize")
                    .formParam("username", "#{username}")
                    .check(status().is(302),
                            headerRegex("Location", "${redirect_uri}#access_token=(.*?)&")
                                    .find().transform(string -> {
                                        try {
                                            return decode(string, "UTF-8");
                                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        return string;
                                    }).saveAs("token")
                    )
    );

    FeederBuilder.Batchable<String> feedUsers = csv("data/temp.csv").circular();

    {
        log.info("Simulation is about to start!");
        log.info("Max Duration: ${MAX_DURATION} seconds, Number of Users: ${NUMBER_OF_USERS} RampUp: within ${RAMP_UP} seconds");


        SetUp testSetup = setUp(
                scn1.feed(feedUsers.transform((key, value) -> {
                            log.info("here ------------- " + value);
                            return key.equals("username") ? value + "" : value;
                        }
                )).injectOpen(atOnceUsers(NUMBER_OF_USERS))
        ).maxDuration(MAX_DURATION);

        testSetup.protocols(httpProtocol).assertions(
                global().successfulRequests().percent().gte(90.0),
                global().responseTime().mean().lte(6000),
                global().failedRequests().percent().lte(10.0),
                forAll().responseTime().max().lte(10000),
                forAll().responseTime().mean().lte(6000),
                forAll().failedRequests().percent().lte(10.0)
        );
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working now.

The feeder should be directly chained to the scenario.

```
ScenarioBuilder scn1 = scenario("states").feed(feedUsers).exec(
    ...
);
```

Rather than on the setUp method.